# How to show the progress status & how to check whether all files are uploaded using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating multiple file upload where i am uploading files to remote api till now it works fine and here are  my issues .

1. If i drop multiple file it has be uploaded one by one so **How can i find whether all file has been uploaded or not so that after all files has been uploaded then i can a run another function**  for ex say i have 3 file to upload and when i upload api calls like 1sfile --> 2nd file --> 3rd file after the total upload is successful i want to call a function and
2. in this process **how can i show a static progress as it is uploading one by one progress will come multiple times instead for till total files complete i want to show progress**
   below is my upload code::

   function uploadImage(e) 
   {
        var upload_count=0,fail_count=0;

   ```
   for(let i=0;i<e.files.length;i++){
       let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       let formData = new FormData();
       let images = e.files[i];
       formData.set('file',images);

       xhr.onreadystatechange = state => { 


           if(xhr.status==201){
               upload_count++;
               if(upload_count==e.files.length){
                console.log("completed all")

               }
           }
           else if(xhr.status==400){
               fail_count++;

               if(fail_count==e.files.length){

               }
           }
           console.log("i="+i)
           console.log("lenght=="+e.files.length)


       } 
       xhr.open("POST", '<some api>');  
       xhr.send(formData);
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: The below answer isn't right for you?

Comment: Have you found another solution than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you well-known approach to make upload progress bar using Jquery.

```js
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
                if (percentComplete === 1) {
                    $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                }
            }
        }, false);

        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "you_api_path",
    data: your_data,
    success: function (data) {
     $('#status').html('<b>Uploaded!!!</b>')
    }
});
```

```css
.progress {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    transition: width .3s;
}
.progress.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnzwcgbs/